# Do we come to a contradiction if we accept completeness axiom for rational numbers?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I found the following formulation of the completeness axiom:

> If two non-empty sets ($A$ and $B$) are such that for any two elements
> from the first and second sets ($a$ and $b$, respectively) it is true that $a \le b$,
> then there is a number $c$ such that $a \le c$ and $c \le b$.

It is also said that this axiom does not hold for rational numbers. However, if we take two non-empty sets ($A$ and $B$) such that $a \le b$ and find among the elements of the two sets such $a$ and such $b$ that $a = b$, then we can say that we found such $c$ ($c = a = b$) that $a \le c$ and $c \le b$. So, for that case it seems to me that the axiom holds also for rational numbers.

Shouldn't it be the case that in the formulation of the axiom we should requests that for any $a$ and $b$ it should be the case that $a < b$ (instead of $a \le b$)? But even in this case we can also find another rational number $c$ (c = (max(a) + min(b)) / 2) such that $a \le c$ and $c \le b$.

So, it looks to me that the completeness axiom holds for rational numbers **if we stay in the domain of rational numbers**. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: It should be $a\le c\le b$ for all a and b I guess. Consider the set of rational numbers above and below $\sqrt2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While between any two numbers there is a rational number, this doesn't save completeness. Let $A=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}: q^2<2\}$ and $B=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}: q^2>2,q>0\}$. Then every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$, but there is no rational which is simultaneously $\ge$ every element of $A$ and $\le$ every element of $B$.

The point is that completeness looks at the interaction between **sets of** numbers, not just individual numbers themselves. So while $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ look similar in some ways (namely, each is a dense linear order without endpoints), completeness totally breaks for $\mathbb{Q}$ but holds for $\mathbb{R}$.

This "points-to-sets" shift can be subtle at first, and easy to miss. In your OP for example you start talking about sets $A$ and $B$ but wind up talking about individual numbers $a$ and $b$, and this is what makes it look like some semblance of completeness holds in $\mathbb{Q}$: while for any specific $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ there will be a rational number between them, there is no rational number which is between the *sets* $A$ and $B$ in the appropriate sense - no single rational $c$ which works for *all* possible choices of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: But still, my point seems to remain valid, if we take two sets of rational numbers (with the above mentioned properties), than we always can find such a rational number c that satisfy the above mentioned properties of c ($a \le c \le b$). So, if we stay in the domain of rational numbers, it looks like the completeness axiom holds for them. We can destroy this property by introduction of irrational numbers (i.e. $\sqrt{2}$). But why can't we have a self-consistent theory of rational numbers with the completeness theorem? Within this theory the irrational numbers just do not exist.

Comment: @Roman "But still, my point seems to remain valid, if we take two sets of rational numbers (with the above mentioned properties), than we always can find such a rational number c that satisfy the above mentioned properties of c" - in the example above, what $c$ exactly do you have in mind? What rational do you think is simultaneously $\ge$ every rational whose square is $<2$, and $\le$ every rational whose square is $>2$? Note that defining the $A$ and $B$ above did **not** require referencing irrationals: "$\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x^2<2\}$" and "$\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x^2>2\}$" only refer to rationals.